# Disable Intellij Source Root Inspection

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

Our Clojure applications have config files in EDN format.  I like to edit them as Clojure files so I get completion, formatting and so on, but they live in the root of our projects and so are not under the `src/` directory, and hence not under a source root.  Intellij therefore gives me a warning for all my config files saying something like `File application.conf is not under a source root`.

I don't want to make the project root into a source root because that doesn't make sense, but I'm also happy that my `.conf` files are not under a source root.  Is there a way to disable this inspection?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gphilipp/bdd-guide-clojure has a solution for .clj files in a directory "features" or "test", perhaps not convenient for .clj files in the root:

To ged rid of the warning message, add this to your project.clj:

```
:test-paths ["features" "test"]
```

Click the refresh button in the Leiningen toolwindow, and verify that the warning is gone.